# Why can I not access the data attribute of an element with jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
    <div  class="button disabled dialogLink"
        id="edit"  
        data-action="Edit" >
        <div class="sprite-blank" ></div>
    </div>
```

This javascript

```
$('.dialogLink')
    .click(function () {
        adminDialog(this);
        return false;
    });


function adminDialog($link) {
    "use strict";
        link = {
            action: $link.data('action') || ''
```

I get an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'data'
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong. It seems very simple code so I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: you may have to use jQUery($link).data()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first create a jQuery object for using jQuery object's methods like `data` method. You can use  `dataset` object:

```
$link.dataset.action
```

or jQuery `data` method:

```
$($link).data('action')
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that $link.attr('data-action') would also work?

Comment: @Anne If `$link` is a jQuery object(_which in your code is not_), yes, you are right.

Comment: Otherwise `$link.getAttribute('data-action')` should work (where `getAttribute()` is a native DOM method).

Comment: Looking at my code I think it changed from before. Because am I right in saying that people normally name jQuery objects with a $ before them.  Maybe before I had adminDialog($(this));

Comment: Yes, people often use a `$` prefix for variables expected to hold jQuery objects (but of course nothing in the JavaScript language enforces this).

Comment: Problem solved with your help. I found that my code used to be like this: var $link = $(this); adminDialog($link);